# how i can javascript render fusion chart in a for loop?

Tags: php, javascript

i am working with fusion chart which renders from a xml file.

```
var  chart1  = new FusionCharts('FusionCharts/MSColumn3D.swf', ' G01 ', '600', '400', '0', '1');                    
        chart1.setXMLUrl(' G01.xml');
        chart1.render('graph1');
```

want to render nearly 12 graphs that which have ids from php array like bold items.

here chart1, G01 are objects.

i have to do like this

```
 foreach($array as $k)
 {


echo "<script type="text/javascript" >";

 var $k['chartid'] = new FusionCharts('FusionCharts/MSColumn3D.swf', '<?php echo   $k['graphid'];?>', '600', '400', '0', '1');                  
        chart1.setXMLUrl("<?php echo $k['graphid'].'xml';?>");
        chart1.render('<?php echo $k['divid'];?>');//div id from html to render graph
    echo "</script>";
         }
```

but it is not working. help me out to.
thanks

Comment: if it is a copy and past of you code you have many syntax errors. e.g. for `echo "<script type="text/javascript" >";` you need to escape the `"` so that it would look this way `echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >";`  then there are also `?>` and `<?php`missing at the right places (you are mixing up php and html/javascript)